# getting error Undefined property: stdClass::$workingtime

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying get output from database but am getting error like A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$workingtime  below is my code.with controller,model and view.getting error on view near $workingtime

controller:

```
public function employee($id)
{

    $user_record = $this->db->query("select * from usr_data where usr_id=$id")->result();
    $data['title'] = 'User Dashboard';
    $data['user_record'] = null;
    $data['active_courses'] = [];
    $data['active_coursess'] = [];
    $data['course_status'] = [];
    if(count($user_record)) {
        $user_record = $user_record[0];
        $data['title'] = ucwords($user_record->firstname.' '.$user_record->lastname).' Dashboard';
        $data['user_record'] = $user_record;

        $active_courses = $this->base_model->getCourseData($id);
        $active_coursess =$this->base_model->gettestDetails($id);
        $data['active_courses'] = $active_courses;
        if(count($active_courses)) {
            $data['course_status'] = $this->base_model->getCourseStatus($active_courses[0]->obj_id, $id);

            $data['time_details'] = $this->base_model->getActiveCourseTimeSpent($active_courses[0]->obj_id, $id);
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('employe-dashboard', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function gettestDetails($user_id)
{
    return $this->executeSelectQuery("SELECT o.title ,ta.*,tpr.workingtime,tcr.mark_official,(tcr.reached_points/tcr.max_points)*100 as result FROM object_data o,usr_data u,tst_active ta, tst_tests tt,tst_pass_result tpr, tst_result_cache tcr WHERE u.usr_id=ta.user_fi and tt.obj_fi=o.obj_id and ta.test_fi=tt.test_id AND ta.active_id=tpr.active_fi AND tcr.active_fi=ta.active_id AND u.usr_id=$user_id and o.type='tst'");
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Attempts</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php
        foreach($active_courses as $test) { 
            $inner_details = $this->base_model->gettestDetails($user_record->usr_id);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($inner_details); die();
            //   $time_spent = 0;
            // if($inner_details)
            //   $time_spent = $inner_details->workingtime;

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ucfirst($test->title); ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test->workingtime; ?> 

            </td>
            <td> 
                <?PHP echo $test->tries ?>
            </td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying get output from database but am getting error like A PHP Error was encountered am trying get output from database but am getting error like A PHP Error was encountered am trying get output from database but am getting error like A PHP Error was encountered.

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$workingtime.
getting error on view near $workingtime

Comment: Try this <td><?php echo $test['workingtime'];?></td>

Comment: if i write like your code am getting this error       A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Can you please print the output of $test on view?

Comment: just var_dump the $test and add it to the question.

Comment: object(stdClass)[20]
  public 'obj_id' => string '3121' (length=4)
  public 'type' => string 'crs' (length=3)
  public 'title' => string 'Test by aditya' (length=14)
  public 'create_date' => string '2017-10-19 11:49:41' (length=19)
  public 'last_update' => string '2017-10-19 11:49:52' (length=19)
  public 'import_id' => null
  public 'usr_id' => string '3213' (length=4) public 'origin_ts' => string '0' (length=1) and the error getting A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: welp you are iterating over `$active_courses` which comes from `$this->base_model->getCourseData($id);` and doesn't have the property `$workingtime`... as shown by your above output. figure out why your query isn't returning that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may not getting `workingtime` field in model response. Re-Check your SQL query.